# Script does not loaded till refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, html

**simply i am using AddThis Plugin in html and below my code**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid="></script>
```

**and in html tag i used**

```
<div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox"></div>
```

**but it is not working till i refresh page only .. so how can i load this script and make div work once**

Comment: Where did you load the script? Try at the end of the `<body>` tag, the widget might not be set to wait till page finishes loading

Comment: Where did you put the `<script>` tag?

Comment: i put it in index.html

Comment: i put it in end of body and still doesn't load